# can i use more then one task in same line of code

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask

I am creating Download Manager in which I want to download multiple files at the same time and update the progress for each download. I used following line to execute AsyncTask

```
executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,Utility.KEY_DOWNLOAD_PATH);
```

But it doesn't starts multiple AsyncTask. When I click on next download it stops first and starts new download.

Comment: any 1 help me please ??

Comment: any one faced the same problem???